# cshtml aspfor getter not working but the setter

Tags: asp.net, razor, razor-pages

I try to get the data of an input via asp-for from a cshtml page to a cshtml.cs page.

cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea name="InputNameEvent" asp-for="NameEvent" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

cshtml.cs

```
[Required]
[MinLength(5)]
[MaxLength(1024)]
public string NameEvent { get; set; }

public string Name2;

public void OnGet()
{
  NameEvent = "Test";
}
 public void OnPost()
 {
     Name2 = NameEvent;
 }
```

Test is shown in the Textarea, but in OnPost() NameEvent is NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake. I needed to put `<form method="post"></form>` around the div. ALso i needed to add `[BindProperty]` in cshtml.cs and remove the `name` attribute in cshtml.
Thanks to Mike :)

cshtml

```
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea asp-for="NameEvent" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

cshtml.cs

```
[Required]
[MinLength(5)]
[MaxLength(1024)]
[BindProperty]
public string NameEvent { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want form values to be bound to PageModel properties automatically, you must decorate the property with the `BindProperty` attribute:

```
[Required]
[MinLength(5)]
[MaxLength(1024)]
[BindProperty]
public string NameEvent { get; set; }
```

Or you can add multiple attributes separated by commas:

```
[Required, MinLength(5), MaxLength(1024), BindProperty]
public string NameEvent { get; set; }
```

If you are using tag helpers for your inputs, don't supply a `name` attribute. Let the tag helper generate one automatically, which will ensure that posted values match property names. At the moment, your name attribute (`name="InputNameEvent"`) does not match the property name, so model binding cannot match the name/value pair that gets posted to a page property or parameter.

See more about [model binding to PageModel properties in Razor Pages here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-posted-form-values-to-pagemodel-properties).

Comment: Thanks, I´ve did it, but didn´t helped :( The Value is still NULL, no matter what i write or wich Boxtype i choose.
But the page has much interresting Input :)

Comment: Just noticed - remove the `name` attribute from the textarea. I have updated the answer to explain why.

Comment: Did it. But nothing changed :( 
The strange thing is, that i´ve wrote [Required] but it allows me to not write anything in the field.

Comment: You need to show more of your code - for the whole form and the PageModel. The Required attribute on its own does nothing. You also need to activate unobtrusive validation in the client and test ModelState.IsValid on the server: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/validation. You also need to add validation tag helpers to output error messages: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/validation-message-tag-helper

Comment: Thanks. You helped me a lot. I found my mistake :) or maybe just a solution, that does what i want XD